# How to check valid input from user under my restrictions in C?

Tags: c

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve!
How to check valid input from the user under my restrictions in C?

I need to build a "bank simulator" using a switch case, the user provides a char and that will determine what action he would do...
For example, if the user type in `O` he will open a new account.

Now my problem is that I wish for the user to have the option to type in, for example, only a single char but if I use:
`scanf("%c", char)` and the user types in OB33, B33 will be kept in the buffer and the program will keep on going until the next `scanf`.
I also tried using restrictions like `%[OBDWCIPE]` and `fgets` but nothing seems to solve the problem of validating the input...

(Also I need to do the same for an INT and for a DOUBLE...)

how can I avoid it...?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202863/discussion-on-question-by-eladaskenazi-how-to-check-valid-input-from-user-under).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment with code, wrap that code in a main and a do/while.
Use a generous buffer [100].
In `fgets` use `sizeof buf` as the second argument.
Instead of double quotes use single quotes in `buf[1] != "\n"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void) {
    char buf[100];
    do {
        printf("What actions would you like to do:");
        fgets ( buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
        if( '\n' != buf[1])
        {
            printf("not valid");
        }
        printf("string is: %s\n", buf);
    } while ( '\n' != buf[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

With a similar do/while wrapped around `strtol` a long integer can be parsed.
`last` is a pointer to the last character processed by `strtol`. Here a valid input is an integer followed by a newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main ( void) {
    char buf[100];
    do {
        printf("What actions would you like to do:");
        fgets ( buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
        if( '\n' != buf[1])
        {
            printf("not valid");
        }
        printf("string is: %s\n", buf);
    } while ( '\n' != buf[1]);

    long int value = 0;
    char *last = NULL;
    do {
        printf("Enter an integer:");
        fgets ( buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
        value = strtol ( buf, &last, 10);
        if ( ( errno == ERANGE && ( value == LONG_MAX || value == LONG_MIN))
        || ( errno != 0 && value == 0)){// parsing error from strtol
            perror ( "value");
            last = buf;
        }
    } while ( last == buf || '\n' != *last);
    printf ( "value is %ld\n", value);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if they press return without pressing anything else? What if they enter 101 characters and then press return?

Comment: Is testing `buf[1]` always safe in all cases? I used to think not, but I'm beginning to change my mind. `<< /dev/null` results in an infinite loop, but that is easily solved by checking the return value, if one were nice `if(!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { if(ferror(stdin)) perror("Programme"); break; }` (it may print no error on non-`POSIX`.)